# Azure CLI command not returning GUID values for a variable

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-digital-twins

I am trying to follow a MSFT documentation tutorial

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/connect-iot-hololens-azure-digital-twins-unity/5-exercise-create-deploy-arm-template) .

But I am stuck on the below command where I am not able to get $object id.

$objectid=$(az ad sp list --display-name $appreg --query [0].objectId --output tsv)

**

Edit:

**
if I query

az ad sp list --display-name ${appreg}

[image]Not sure why its not displaying the object id.

Comment: can you query this `az ad sp list --display-name ${appreg}` ? and show what is returning?

Comment: @Jayendran yes I can query and getting a json response. However I cant see any element named objectId. not sure how this [0].objectId is working  in the query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property name has changed, it's no longer `objectId`. Instead, it was renamed to `id`. I confirmed it was still `objectId` in az CLI version 2.28.0, but after upgrading to 2.40, the property was different.

So instead of:

```
$objectid=$(az ad sp list --display-name ${appreg} --query [0].objectId --output tsv)
```

Try:

```
$objectid=$(az ad sp list --display-name ${appreg} --query [0].id --output tsv)
```

Comment: @Matthijis seems like it worked!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: great!! I solved with this too. Why are the official docs so outdated...?